HTTP 500/502 errors in the Windows Application Event Log
How does Windows/IIS decide which HTTP 500/502 errors get logged in Windows Application Event log? If I inspect the errors in the event viewer, I can see some HTTP errors but not all. And for example, I can call a page (a CGI script) that returns a 502 but I don't see a log entry for it. Is there a (new) setting somewhere that controls which HTTP errors get logged or not?
I'm almost certain, these errors used to show in the log but something has changed in recent times.
Any clues? Thanks!

Windows/IIS logs HTTP errors like 500 and 502 in several places, including the IIS log files, the Windows Event Viewer (specifically the Application log), and possibly the Failed Request Tracing logs if enabled. However, not all HTTP errors necessarily get logged in the Windows Event Viewer, and this behavior can vary based on several settings and configurations.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7

Thanks, I appreciate that it's possible to troubleshoot. What I'm more interested in is monitoring errors in a general sense. We are using CGI for Perl and Python scripts and would like to capture unhandled exceptions on the application event log. Like I said, I'm sure this used to happen in the past but it's stopped for some reason.
